# Slideout navigation in Swift similar to Facebook

Tags: swift, navigation

I have been following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/78568/create-slide-out-navigation-panel-swift) on how to make a slide out navigation, however I do not need a right side navigation, and the tutorial is not very explanatory as much as it just tells you what to add. I feel as if Im not learning anything, and Im in need of something better. I don't want to use a framework at all. I want to be able to modify, and write it along the guides of a tutorial setting, but this was the only one I could find that didn't use a framework.

It doesn't need to be fancy, just needs to work. After that I should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is easy way to implement side menu in swift project. It's a just class file you can also modify this class. Get it from here: [SlideMenuController](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift)

If you are using StoryBoard just add this code in your didFinishLaunchingWithOptions Method.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

    let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MainViewController") as! MainViewController
    let leftViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("LeftViewController") as! LeftViewController
    let rightViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("RightViewController") as! RightViewController

    let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)

    leftViewController.mainViewController = nvc

    let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController:nvc, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController, rightMenuViewController: rightViewController)

    self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 236.0, green: 238.0, blue: 241.0, alpha: 1.0)
    self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Add your Menu Button with this Code:

```
viewController.addLeftBarButtonWithImage(UIImage(named: "hoge")!)
```

Open and Close manually:

```
// Open
self.slideMenuController()?.openLeft()
self.slideMenuController()?.openRight()

// close
self.slideMenuController()?.closeLeft()
self.slideMenuController()?.closeRight()
```

Comment: I actually have tried that but it was difficult to implement.